# HTML/CSS - Remove top and side margins

Tags: html, css

Here's a shrunken version of a webpage. The black is the background color for a header div I made. My question is how do I eliminate the blue area above and to the sides of it? I would like it to look more like the second image. I tried margin: 0px; for top, left, and right, but nothing changed. Any suggestions?
[image]

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body { 
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#header {
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add margin:0 to the body tag

```
body { 
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Ah I should have figured that out. Was too focused on the header part of the CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that your DIV has a margin, but rather that the BODY has a margin.  Most browsers add this by default, but you can eliminate it with

```
body{ margin: 0; }
```

in your CSS.  Some people like to get rid of these things that browsers add with something called a [cssreset](http://www.cssreset.com/).  This would give you more of a blank slate to begin with.